# Java: Millisecond timestamp string to float

Tags: java, floating-point, timestamp, milliseconds

I have this String: 1303317717.65384 - It's a UNIX timestamp (1303317717) with milliseconds (65384).

How can I convert this to a float in Java? I am always getting 1.06172723E9 when giving it out, but I just want it to be 1303317717.65384.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the code how you are giving out the float so we can help better

Comment: I have 2 clarification questions: 1) You say 65384 is 'milliseconds' - there are only 1000 ms in one second; do you actually mean microseconds? 2) What significant digits do you need from the timestamp? Your example timestamp has 10 digits in the seconds, and (probably) 6 in the microseconds (assuming that is the correct answer to #1). Java float (IEEE 754 32-bit floating point) has just under 16 digits of precision. Depending on your end goal, you may need more digits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to display this with enough precision one within a float variable - you have to use a double.

Demo:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%f", Float.parseFloat("1303317717.65384")));
System.out.println(String.format("%f", Double.parseDouble("1303317717.65384")));
```

yields

```
1303317760.000000
1303317717.653840
```

Answer (score 2):

Floats in Java only have about six digits of precision. You need a double.

If it's in the form of a String, then you can use `Double.parseDouble(String s)`.

Answer (score 0):

A float has insufficient precision. Use a double instead.